# An error occurred while updating the entries - String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datagridview, ado.net

I did this project before with Entity Framework and Microsoft SQL Server 2008 without any problems. I had a table with two simple columns (`ID` and `Name`). I bound them to a `DataGridView` and I had no problem with `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete`.

Now I tried to do same thing but this time with two much complicated tables with auto-increment columns and foreign keys.

When I tried to save inserted information in database I had following exceptions:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.
>
> INNER EXCEPTION: String or binary data would be truncated. The
>   statement has been terminated.

After almost 10 times stop and re-run project error gone without I change anything. What was this error for? And why it gone without I change anythings?

I can not trust to Entity Framework if it want to throw random exceptions without reasons and stop to throw those exceptions after a while.

Comment: Usually this error occurs when the supplied data length is greater than the length specified in database field. Are you sure you didn't change anything in the database or the the inputs ?

Comment: Oh, yes your right, this error occurs when data length is greater than specified length for field in database. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Habib: Re-post that as an answer. :)

Comment: @Habib please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when the supplied data length is greater than the length specified in database field.

Make sure that the database field length is enough to accommodate the input data.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented this but i do not have enough reputation to comment.
I was stuck on this same error.After seeing this answer what i did to quickly find where i am wrong is my using.

```
PM> update-database -force -Verbose
```

Verbose Tag have a look at the Sql Generated for the AutomaticMigrations.

Hope this helps.